# React Native /ECMAScript 6 Syntax

Tags: function, react-native, ecmascript-6, google-places-api, onpress

I can't find great documentation on ECMAScript 6 syntax breakdown. The short hand is awesome but difficult to read sometimes. Can anyone break down the **onPress** function for me? Or point me to some good documentation with the break down of syntax?

I understand this as: onPress we will run a function that take in params of data and null and we will print it out after we have a response. Data and details are the responses from the google api so I have to assume that we aren't actually setting details to null. I just don't understand the function syntax.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder='Search'
    minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
    fetchDetails={true}
    onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
        console.log(data, details);
    }}
```

Comment: [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` value being passed to the argument of the function is [a default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Here's how [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) work.

1. An empty function block looks like this -

   ```
   () => {}
   ```

   which is equivalent to -

   ```
   function () {}
   ```
2. If you add parameters, it looks like -

   ```
   (param1, param2) => {}
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   function(param1, param2) {}
   ```
3. And with a default parameter, it looks like -

   ```
   (param1, param2 = 2) => { return param1 + param 2}
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   function(param1, param2 = 2){
    return param1 + param2;
   }
   ```

   A call to this function can be made with 1 or 2 paramters. If made with a single parameter, it will take param2's value as 2 in the above example by default.

So, in your case, you're setting the value to `null` as a default parameter, if nothing comes in the details of the `onPress` event.